# Need to average grades stored in a Struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, average

Ok, so I am working with reading data from a file into a Struct in C++ and I have a program that does just that. It reads a file that contains students' names, each student's grade in the class, and each student's major. What I am trying to figure out is how to collect and average the grades I have stored in my Struct and output the average along with the highest and lowest grade.

I am hoping that someone on here can give me a push in the right direction. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct studentInfo
{
    string studentName;
    double studentGrade;
    string studentMajor;
};

int main ()
{
    cout << "Please enter the file you wish to open:" << endl;
    string fileName;
    cin >> fileName;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(fileName.c_str());

    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "Error! Cannot find specified file!" << endl;

        return 1;
    }

    studentInfo array[11];
    int i;

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i ++)
    {
        infile >> array[i].studentName >>  array[i].studentGrade >>array[i].studentMajor;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i].studentName << " ";
        cout << array[i].studentGrade << " ";
        cout << array[i].studentMajor << "\n ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Just in case you were wondering, the data files that are being read into the Struct are .dat files formatted as such: (studentName [tab] studentGrade [tab] studentMajor)

Like this:

> Tom    99  CS
>
> Clair  56  MAT
>
> Sue    96  CS
>
> Casey  88  MAT
>
> James  45  CS
>
> Frank  78  GS
>
> Ben    52  ARCH
>
> Laren  62  CS
>
> Harry  78  IS
>
> Sam    100 CS
>
> Jennifer   68  MAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to collect and average the grades I have stored in my Struct and output the average along with the highest and lowest grade

You're already reading the grades into `studentInfo array[11];`, and looping over them to output them: as you loop keep track of the `total`, `min` and `max` using extra variables, initialised to `0`, `array[0].studentgrade` and `array[0].studentgrade` respectively: you can use `+=` to accumulate a total, and `if` tests to conditionally replace the `min` and `max` with lower/higher values.  You can output an average by dividing the total by the number of records.

Comment: @ebonymessiah you're welcome - happy coding!  Cheers.